# Why stripe first send invoice.payment_failed webhook

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment

Why stripe first send invoice.payment_failed webhook webhook event even subscription transaction is successfully completed

I know in unsuccessful transaction it is common but every transaction(every subscription payment) stripe send invoice.payment_failed. Please explain this why stripe send that event.

I check stripe webhook event it like
Subscription created
Invoice failed
So on....
Last checkout session completed

Comment: I recommend you reach out to Stripe support : https://support.stripe.com/contact with the Subscription id. They'll be able to investigate further and explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I can handle this , how to differentiate that so that invoice.payment_failed event not actually failed and not save as a failed entry in my database.

As I mentioned, this failure isn't surfaced at Payment Intent and Charge-level, so you could listen to events for those objects rather than Invoices and solve your problem.

If we look at the `invoice.payment_failed` event specifically, it would be sent with `charge:null` if:
1-The downstream Payment Intent requires additional actions (eg. 3DSecure)
2-The customer failed this additional action.
3-The Invoice has no Payment Method to charge (missing or not set as default on Customer / Subscription)

If you're happy ignoring all of the above scenarios, then feel free to ignore the `invoice.payment_failed` event if it includes `charge:null`.
If you don't want to ignore some of these scenarios (I'm thinking of (2) specifically), then what you should do is listen to other events like `payment_intent.payment_failed` to get more context as to why the `invoice.payment_failed` triggered.

Comment: Stripe send first invoice.payment_failed event with charge=null and than send again invoice.payment_failed event after the other event with charge=[charge id]  FYI:- This is subscription payment failed scenario.

Comment: Hey @Lucky2501 ,In subscription succeed scenario below event send  first send invoice.payment_failed with charge=null after stripe send invoice.payment_succeded. So why stripe first send invoice.payment_failed with charge=null

Comment: I wouldn’t suggest looking at the charge attribute, it’s a vestigial attribute from when the parenting flow was Invoice > Charge instead of Invoice > Payment Intent > Charge as it is now. 
I think you’re seeing it null because the failed charge from additional actions doesn’t populate as a proper charge object, even though it still triggers the invoice.payment_failed event

Comment: To clarify, the Invoice.charge attribute isn’t useless, you’ll see something here eg from a card decline. This is just a quirky situation where a charge fails on the backend but doesn’t come up as a charge

Comment: So we differentiate invoice.payment_failed  event like if charge = null  so that first event not save on our database right?

Comment: Yes it’s a good point, that would work as well. The other situation where that would happen is if you didn’t have a payment method to charge, or didn’t have it set as default on the Customer/Subscription

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, Now I just want to curious about why stripe send invoice.payment_failed with charge = Null and than payment failed scenario again send invoice.payment_failed event with charge id and payment succeed scenario send invoice.payment_succeded. Stripe send invoice.payment_failed event initially even subscription payment is successfully completed.

Comment: Honestly, I don’t know… I think it’s a historical issue rather than a technical one. I mentioned earlier that the invoice.charge attribute was vestigial. My understanding is that invoices used to generate charges, instead of payment intents (which then generate the charge). I wouldn’t be surprised that SCA regulations meant devs had to shoehorn the payment intent flow into invoicing, which led to weird situations like this. I think the best way to look at it is that the invoice.payment_failed event really means invoice.payment_not_succeeded, which then kind of makes sense.

Comment: Ok Lucky2501.  When I make subscription payment below webhook event are called                   invoice.updated
 invoice.created
invoice.finalized
subscription created
invoice failed
payment intent created
payment_intent.requires_action
invoice.payment_action_required
customer.updated
payment intent succeeded
invoice.payment_succeeded
checkout session completed
charge.succeeded
invoice.updated
invoice paid
subscription updated
customer.updated

Comment: And one more thing I generate stripe checkout page using session code which mention in below link. 
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart                             SessionCreateParams params = SessionCreateParams.builder() .addLineItem(       SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder().setPrice(prices.getData().get(0).getId()).setQuantity(1L).build())         .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.SUBSCRIPTION).setSuccessUrl(YOUR_DOMAIN + "/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}")
          .setCancelUrl(YOUR_DOMAIN + "/cancel.html")

Comment: When you say : “invoice.finalized subscription created invoice failed payment intent created” do you mean “customer.subscription.created, invoice.payment_failed, payment_intent.created” ? If so, that sounds normal. Essentially, when the invoice finalises at Subscription creation, it creates the payment_intent and attempts to complete it. If it doesn’t, the invoice.payment_failed triggers. Now, because this fires even if the failure is temporary (pending additional action), it doesn’t make a lot of sense, but I’m assuming the system doesn’t deal with that ambiguity.

Comment: This is why I was trying to help with the invoice.payment_not_succeeded analogy before. Basically, when you get the invoice.payment_failed event, what you should understand is that Stripe tried to finalise an Invoice payment but couldn’t do it for whatever reason. Don’t think of it as the payment *actually failing*.

Comment: Yes this is not actually payment failed when stripe send the first time send invoice.payment_failed event my problem is i write a code when invoice.payment_failed are called excuate that code and add faield payment entry in our database stripe send the temporary invoice.payment_failed event. When actually subscription payment are failed that time add entry in my db. But stripe send invoice.payment_failed event with charge =null so add unnecessary entry on my db. I write that code only on when payment are actually failed due to authentication and low balance etc....

Comment: So I can prevent that means how prevent when stripe send invoice.payment_failed with charge = null so that is not payment failed and not store in our database.

Comment: when the stripe send the invoice.payment_failed event with charge = null so consider that event not failed and not save as a failed payment entry in our database right??

Comment: I just tested it on my end.  
You can do this this way - the only thing you need to know is that if the payment requires authentication and the customer fails it, then you'll still only get `invoice.payment_failed` with `charge:null`. It might be okay though : the checkout session won't complete so long as authentication is not succeeded, and the customer won't leave the session.  
What I would suggest you do is to apply your condition with `charge:null` on the `invoice.payment_failed` event as you suggested, but also listen for Payment Intent events as they would provide more info anyway

Comment: 1)invoice.updated
2)invoice.created
3)invoice.finalized
4)subscription created
5)invoice failed
6)payment intent created
7)payment_intent.requires_action
8)invoice.payment_action_required
9)customer.updated
10)payment intent succeeded
11)invoice.payment_succeeded
12)checkout session completed
13)charge.succeeded
14)invoice.updated
15)invoice paid
16)subscription updated
17)customer.updated this webhook event are called during/after the subscription payment. See the no5 event that hold charge = null.

Comment: When I make failed payment using stripe testing card that time stripe first send invoice.payment_failed with charge = null and after stripe send invoice.payment_failed with charge = [charge id]. And customer faced authentication error and insufficient balance that time stripe send teo invoice.payment_failed event first is charge =null and second one is charge = charge id.

Comment: ... this comment thread is starting to get long. *If your customer fails authentication, you won't get a charge in the `invoice.payment_failed` events*. Is this something you want to ignore as well ? Only you can answer this question. If you do want to ignore it, good. If you don't, you'll need to listen to other events to get more information about why `invoice.payment_failed` triggered.

Comment: No if I ignore invoice.payment_failed event so we don't know subscription payment done or not because we set some Metadata so it is available in invoice.payment_failed event.

Comment: My question is why stripe send invoice.payment_failed with charge = null in subscription payment succeed. Stripe send first invoice.payment_failed and after some event send invoice.payment_succeded which mention is above comments. In failed scenario stripe send first invoice.payment_failed event with charge = null and after send invoice.payment_failed event with charge = [ charge id]

Comment: I don't think we're understanding each other. I've edited my response, hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Ok, and sorry for that currentlly i am so confused, tell me one thing how many webhook events  send stripe during/after subscription payment scenario.

Comment: Please check below scenario from your side              generate stripe subscription checkout page using session code I mentioned in above comments and make a subscription payment using stripe testing card which is 4242.... and check the webhook event on stripe dashboard. Checking above scenario in stripe test mode only. Thanks

Comment: I can replicate what you're seeing if I have the Radar rule 'request3DS if supported for card'.  The *4242 card is a bit quirky too. If it needs to be authenticated, it will throw a rare 3DS exception where 3DS is required, doesn't succeed, but the payment is authenticated anyway (you should see this from the payment's timeline). Anyway, this is very much normal - as I mentioned, the `invoice.payment_failed`+`charge:null` triggers if additional actions are required. Then, when authentication succeeds (or sort of succeeds, in the case of *4242), `invoice.payment_succeeded` triggers.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information available, this could be due to your end payment requiring additional actions (eg 3DSecure).

When payment intents are confirmed, it returns a Charge object.
If additional actions are required as a result of this confirmation, the charge is failed.

This failure isn't surfaced as a payment_intent.payment_failed event or charge.failed event, however if an Invoice is parented to your flow (which it is for Subscriptions), an invoice.payment_failed event would trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Lucky2501 but how to handle that scenario because I write some code in invoice.payment_failed event so it execute that code add fail payment entry in my local database after around 3 second succeed webhook call and add same entry with payment succeed how I can handle this , how to differentiate that so that invoice.payment_failed event not actually failed and not save as a failed entry in my database.