# Prevent save duplicate entry in our local database during stripe webhook

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment

In my Spring Boot application, I'm listening to webhook events from Stripe, specifically "invoice.payment_failed" and "invoice.payment_succeeded." I've implemented the following logic to manage subscription details in my local database:

For "invoice.payment_failed" events, I retrieve the subscription details from Stripe, check if it exists in my local database, and if it does, I update it with the latest Stripe subscription details. If not, I save the subscription in my local database.

Similarly, for "invoice.payment_succeeded" events, I follow the same logic of checking and updating or saving subscriptions in my local database.

The challenge arises when Stripe sends both webhook events consecutively during a single subscription payment. Each event is considered a new request, and Spring Boot handles them in a request pool. Occasionally, both requests execute simultaneously, and if the subscription is not found in my database, it can lead to duplicate entries.

So how to solve that problem. Pls guide me

Try to guide and solve that type of scenarios during stripe webhook.

For that type of scenarios I have one approach

1. lock database row

But that is not best practices for big level so provide some best practices to resolving that type of scenarios.

How to solving that type of scenarios Pls guide me

Answer (score 0):

I think the duplicate scenario you’re referring to is related to the quirk you reported here:
[Why stripe first send invoice.payment_failed webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894907/why-stripe-first-send-invoice-payment-failed-webhook/76934138?noredirect=1#comment135634061_76934138)

The invoice.payment_failed event can trigger from a payment requiring actions, which might be completed automatically and result in a invoice.payment_succeeded instants later.

This quirk should only happen for the first invoice of a Subscription, when the customer is on session and can authenticate immediately after the requires action issue.

Going back to your db issue, what I would do is ignore the invoice.payment_failed event conditionally:
-ignore if invoice.billing_reason == subscription_create.
After all, if the Invoice payment fails at the start of the Subscription, I don’t see much point in storing the Subscription yet.

-ignore if invoice.charge is null.
This refers to the quirk outlined above, though it would also apply to an invoice payment that fails because the Customer has no default payment method to charge.

-listen to payment_intent-level and charge-level events instead, as they don’t have the above quirk. But they won’t contain the Subscription, you’d need to retrieve and expand resources to get it.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects

--EDIT--
I think you might have changed this sentence of your post:

> Stripe sends both webhook events *consecutively* during a single subscription payment.

So maybe it's not just the quirk above, but also cases like a customer failing a payment, then submitting it again successfully.
The first solution (ignore invoice.payment_failed and invoice.billing_reason==subscription_create) would still work here I think.

Alternatively, you can implement a queue on your handler that keeps events in the order they generate (as per their `created` timestamp), and submitting them to your db according to it's read limit.
This is a good practice regardless, since Stripe can send the same event twice occasionally:
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#handle-duplicate-events

Comment: thanks for replying   but I want to store subscription with incomplete in my database. If user make a payment and pay with card and stripe say insufficient balance that time stripe subscription is incomplete and after 23 hours change status to unpaid or canceled. That incomplete status is occurs in invoice.payment_failed event.

Comment: Is save subscription with incomplete status in our database? What you think  or avoid that.

Comment: Now I am thinking store only stripe subscription id when invoice.payment_succeded. After that when customer want  check their subscription details we can retrieve directly from stripe using STRIPE API. Is it best practices?

Comment: It's up to you to decide if you should store incomplete Subscriptions in your db. Doing so definitely makes things more complicated with your issue. I've edited my response, if you do want to capture incomplete Subs, I think your best bet would be to implement a buffer queue for events, which you feed to your DB in a timely manner so that it doesn't duplicate anything.

Comment: Yeah you right ✅️ implement Kafka or othe msg service like Kafka. But read my third comment and share your thoughts

Comment: It's again a matter of personal preference at this point. If in your app, it takes a customer a long time to pick their plan and checkout, then you should probably allow your customers to retry incomplete Subscriptions. For this, you could list Subscriptions per customer and confirm their downstream intent using its `client_secret`: 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer 
Otherwise, I would simplify, and make the customer proceed to checkout again with a brand new Sub. Stripe will expire incomplete Subs automatically, so you can forget about them.

Comment: Ok now tell me one more thing on below flow        store only stripe subscription id in our database in succeed payment. Now customer want to see their sub details now we fetch the subscription from stripe and see details to customer. Currently we store subscription status and start date and end date. Is the best practices?

Comment: There really aren't any 'best practices' for what Subscription information you show to your customers - you show whatever you want. What I like showing is the card brand and last4 that is charged for the Subscription - which you can do by retrieving the Payment Method object: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve

Comment: No no, just show subscription status. I current flow we store subscription details like subscription status and start date and end date in our local database now store only stripe subscription id only and show subscription status to user using fetch details using stripe api. So I want to avoiding store subscription details in our db.

Comment: Luck2501 PLS ans above comments

Answer (score 0):

When a subscription payment fails, Stripe will perform smart retries to recover it. Therefore, it's totally possible to receive a `invoice.paid` followed by a `invoice.payment_failed` when the card finally has sufficient funds to pay the invoice when retried.

Please also note that the subscription status will only change when all retries failed, and the status that the subscription will transition to is determined by your [settings](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#settings). I don't have the details of your backend logic, but I'd like to suggest reconsidering updating your internal subscription status based on `invoice.payment_failed` because this can be ephemeral. If you want to mirror the Stripe subscription status and update your DB when a Stripe subscription status changes, you can subscribe to `customer.subscription.updated`.

Comment: Now you say update local store subscription details using subscribe subscription.update event so when I save the first subscription with incomplete status. According to you I follow approach like save subscription in subconscious.create event and update subscription details using subscription.update event. Now problem is when stripe send update event first and create event later or both event execute parallel and check if subscription details not found in local than save it. So add duplicate subscription entry with created status and updated status